# Undefined Property in Javascript For Loop

Tags: javascript, scope

I can't see an answer to this question on StackOverflow however I have a feeling it is going to be embarrassing but here goes.

```
var project_ID;
var projectName;

var tabulatorRowData = {};
var projectData = []
var mainColumnHeading = {
        "id": project_ID,
        "projectID": project_ID,
        "projectName": projectName
}
tabulatorRowData.projectData = projectData;
for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    mainColumnHeading.id = 1;
    mainColumnHeading.projectID = 2;
    mainColumnHeading.projectName = "project Name";
    tabulatorRowData.projectData.push(mainColumnHeading);
    for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
        tabulatorRowData.projectData[j].hours = j;
        tabulatorRowData.projectData[j].progress = j+20;
    }
}
console.log(tabulatorRowData);
console.log(JSON.stringify(tabulatorRowData));
```

I am testing and running this in Eclipse using the Node.js library and it returns the following error;

```
tabulatorRowData.projectData[j].hours = j;
TypeError: Cannot set property 'hours' of undefined
```

Now if I place the offending code within the `for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {` it works so I know it is a scoping issue but can't figure what declaration I could make to fix it.

Comment: Modify `j` to `i`,         `tabulatorRowData.projectData[ i ].hours = j;`

Comment: I can't do that as this is a separate loop

Comment: array value is undefined when `j>i`

Comment: _“I can't do that as this is a separate loop”_ - well I would not necessarily call them separate, considering that one loop is nested inside the other here ... which also seems to be the cause of your problem, because you always try to run through ten elements in the inner loop no matter what - even if you haven’t added that many elements in the outer loop yet. I think you might need `for (j=0; j < i; j++)` here perhaps …? Or make them actually _separate_ loops, instead of nested. (Hard to tell because a proper explanation of what this is supposed to do is missing from your question.)

Comment: @CBroe yes agree.  I edited the question to reflect what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `projectData` initialized to an empty array, the inner `for` loops run for 10 times for each main iteration. Said that, for first iteration with `i=0`, `tabulatorRowData.projectData[1]` will be undefined and so on.

You can move the inner loop after the main loop

```
for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    mainColumnHeading.id = 1;
    mainColumnHeading.projectID = 2;
    mainColumnHeading.projectName = "project Name";
    tabulatorRowData.projectData.push(mainColumnHeading);
}

for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
    tabulatorRowData.projectData[j].hours = j;
    tabulatorRowData.projectData[j].progress = j+20;
}
```

**Note**, the item pushed in `tabulatorRowData.projectData` is `mainColumnHeading` and the reference of the object is same for all the array items. Which means after the loop, the final result will be an array of 10 items pointing to the same object.

Comment: Thankyou.  That is very helpful and I must admit I feel a bit silly.!

Comment: @Alexander - Not a problem. Do see my note in the answer.

Comment: @Alexander - If this the issue then you need to make sure `mainColumnHeading` is pointing to different object in the for loop. The easiest will be to move `var mainColumnHeading =` inside the for loop.

Comment: @Alexander - Were you able to fix?

Comment: @Alexander - Let me know if I can provide some help around this.

Comment: Many thanks.  If you have the time, I did add a further clarification to the question at the bottom which shows what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: In an object, keys are unique, you can not have same key with different values. You will need to change the data structure for this

Comment: Also, I would suggest you to post the new edit as a separate question with more detailing.

Comment: No, thanks I will figure it out.   I can't afford any more down votes :-)  Although the comments have been very helpful

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the nesting of the loops is wrong, you need to take them apart:

```
for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    mainColumnHeading.id = 1;
    mainColumnHeading.projectID = 2;
    mainColumnHeading.projectName = "project Name";
    tabulatorRowData.projectData.push(mainColumnHeading);
}
for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
    tabulatorRowData.projectData[j].hours = j;
    tabulatorRowData.projectData[j].progress = j+20;
}
```

The reason is that you are adding items to `tabulatorRowData.projectData` in the `i`-loop, so you can't access all 10 of them at once until the `i`-loop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

This question caused a great deal of discussion and probably reflects the poor framing of the question; so in terms of the problem above the answers are correct but because I did not mention what the intent was those that answered were not able to address the real problem.  So though I would post the correct implementation to help anyone else having this issue.

Basically what I wanted to do is to create an object with a number of `name:value` pairs that could be generated from a database rather than a static declaration, and I wanted to do this for each returned row of the database.

Although not stated in the question, it turned out that adding properties to objects can be done using the `.` notation or `square bracket` notation and the scope of the `.` notation is limited.

Anyway, here is the answer and I hope it is of help.

```
var tabulatorRowData = {};
var projectData = []
tabulatorRowData.projectData = projectData;
for (var j=0;j<10;j++){
    var mainColumnHeading = new Object();
    mainColumnHeading.id = j;
    mainColumnHeading.projectID = j*2;
    mainColumnHeading.projectName = "newName"+j;
    tabulatorRowData.projectData.push(mainColumnHeading); 
    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        var hours = "hours"+i;
        var progress = "progress"+i;
            tabulatorRowData.projectData[j][hours] = i;
            tabulatorRowData.projectData[j][progress] = 2*i
    }
}

console.log(tabulatorRowData);
console.log(JSON.stringify(tabulatorRowData));
```

The output looks like this:

```
{"projectData":[{"id":0,"projectID":0,"projectName":"newName0","hours0":0,"progress0":0,"hours1":1,"progress1":2,"hours2":2,"progress2":4,"hours3":3,"progress3":6,"hours4":4,"progress4":8},
{"id":1,"projectID":2,"projectName":"newName1","hours0":0,"progress0":0,"hours1":1,"progress1":2,"hours2":2,"progress2":4,"hours3":3,"progress3":6,"hours4":4,"progress4":8},
{"id":2,"projectID":4,"projectName":"newName2","hours0":0,"progress0":0,"hours1":1,"progress1":2,"hours2":2,"progress2":4,"hours3":3,"progress3":6,"hours4":4,"progress4":8},
{"id":3,"projectID":6,"projectName":"newName3","hours0":0,"progress0":0,"hours1":1,"progress1":2,"hours2":2,"progress2":4,"hours3":3,"progress3":6,"hours4":4,"progress4":8},
{"id":4,"projectID":8,"projectName":"newName4","hours0":0,"progress0":0,"hours1":1,"progress1":2,"hours2":2,"progress2":4,"hours3":3,"progress3":6,"hours4":4,"progress4":8}]}
```

Which is the form required say for a Tabulator table.